# TypeORM AfterInsert() can't add userId in another table

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I have a user entity:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  //...

  @OneToOne(() => UserActive)
  userActive: UserActive;

  @AfterInsert()
  public async handleAfterInsert() {
    const userActive = new UserActive();
    userActive.token = randomString();
    userActive.user = this;
    await getConnection().getRepository(UserActive).save(userActive);
  }
}
```

and `UserActive`:

```
export class UserActive extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    length: 25,
    unique: true,
  })
  token: string;

  @OneToOne(() => User)
  @JoinColumn()
  user: User;
}
```

I need to insert module `token` and user `id` into `UserActive`. `this` in line `userActive.user = this;` is object `user` (of course with `id`).

When I insert new user, then TypeORM return error:

> Key (userId)=(438dc281-3f03-45b0-bee8-76aecc894d14) is not present in
> table "user".

Of course when i change to:

```
userActive.user = '438dc281-3f03-45b0-bee8-76aecc894d14'
```

then everything works correctly.

I'm using Next.js

***EDIT:***

I insert new user using:

```
const connection = getConnection().manager;

const user = new User();
user.name = name;
user.email = email;
user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
await connection.save(user);
```

And I change method `handleAfterInsert` to:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;
  
   //...

  @OneToOne(() => UserActive)
  userActive: UserActive;

  @AfterInsert()
  public async handleAfterInsert() {
    const userActive = new UserActive();
    userActive.token = randomString();
    userActive.user = this;
    await getConnection().manager.save(userActive);
  }
}
```

But Nest returns the same error as before.

***EDIT 2:***

I found this problem: [Retrieving ID in @AfterInsert operation](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3563)

And I try change my method afterInsert to:

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class UserSubscriber
  implements EntitySubscriberInterface<User> {
  listenTo() {
    return User;
  }

  async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<User>) {
    const userActive = new UserActive();
    userActive.token = randomString();
    userActive.user = event.entity;
    await getConnection().getRepository(UserActive).save(userActive);
  }
}
```

But now nothing is added to table `user active`, only is added new user to table `user`.

Comment: Please update your question to include UserActive entity, and the @JoinColumn.

Comment: @Edward I update my post

Answer (score 3):

I suspect it's because the save(user) and save(userActive) are being done in separate database transactions, so the User has not yet been committed to the database when save(userActive) is executed -- even though it has its id generated, it is not yet committed -- so the save(UserActive) transaction cannot see the new user so you see error "Key (userId=xxx) is not present in table user".

You may be able to fix this but using [entity manager](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entity-manager-api.md) instead of [repository](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/working-with-repository.md). You cannot use repository because it is limited to a single entity, but you are dealing here with 2 entities (user & userActive).

Change your 2 saves to use the same entity manager, something like this:

Saving user:

```
const connection: Connection = await createConnection();
const manager = connection.manager;
var user = new User();
user.Name = "John";
// etc
// N.B. Use entity manager, not repository, to save: 
await manager.save(user);
```

and likewise saving the userActive record:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
// ...
    @AfterInsert()
    public async handleAfterInsert() {
        const userActive = new UserActive();
        userActive.token = randomString();
        userActive.user = this;
        // N.B. Use entity manager, not repository, here: 
        await getConnection().manager.save(userActive);
    }
```

UPDATED ANSWER

I tested my answer above and indeed it does not work - if I enable [typeorm logging](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/logging.md) I can see there there are two separate transactions.

I found the answer in the same [post](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3563#issuecomment-460054971) as you: further down it says you must enable the 'subscribers' connection option - this is not obvious at all.

I did it like this: Create 'afteruser.ts' in 'subscriber' folder in the project, and make sure this folder is included on the 'subscribers' connection option in ormconfig.json:

```
{
  // ...
  "logging": true,
  "entities": [ "entity/*.js" ],
  "subscribers": [ "subscriber/*.js" ],
  // ...
}
```

I suspect the problem in your updated solution is this line, because this creates a new transaction:

```
await getConnection().getRepository(UserActive).save(userActive);
```

You need to use the same "entity manager", like this:

```
await event.manager.getRepository(UserActive).save(userActive);
```

Comment: If it works for you I'll edit my answer to remove "I suspect".

Comment: @michal I tested and indeed my original solution did not work, even if my explanation is correct. As you found, handleAfterInsert has a known bug that it starts a new transaction, so you have to use EventSubscriber instead. Possibly you have missed that you need event.manager to get the same transaction as the main save. Also, make sure the event subscriber is being called by adding a break point or logging to the console.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the `await` keyword and make it async, but it starts another transaction which may lead to unexpected errors if you have high write traffic.

It states in the docs that `Note: Do not make any database calls within a listener, opt for subscribers instead.`

Make your after-insertion upserts using subscribers, otherwise, listeners may behave unexpectedly, such as starting another transaction before the first one finishes, using subscribers you can kinda *intercept* transactions before committing, which means if you want to create a child entity after the parent is created, you can do this in the same transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, for some reasons listeners like `@AfterInsert` are executed before the transaction is committed.

To solve that, you need to use subscribers https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md

And do your transactions with `entity.manager.getRepository(Entity).find(...)`