# Track dr for changes | NestJS

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am using NestJS and PostgreSQL.
I need to watch for changes in a table in the database and when some changes appear (adding a record or changing a field), needs to reproduce the methods.

How can I do this in NestJS? What are the best practices?

Comment: I don't believe NestJS has opinion on this. You'll need to see how your ORM (or whatever) handles it, not NestJS itself.

Comment: I believe you find something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215930/typeorm-afterinsert-cant-add-userid-in-another-table